# Strange rotation transform behavior when mixed with other transforms in an animation

Tags: css

I'm working with some basic CSS animation, and I can't seem to figure out the rendering logic for various transforms. If I do the following animation, the target rotates from 0 to 350deg clockwise, as expected.

```
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(350deg);
  }
}
```

However, when I add in other transforms, the rotation starts taking shortcuts (going from 0 to 350deg counter-clockwise). This even results in no visible rotation if I'm going from 0 to 360deg. Here's an example:

```
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(500px) rotate(350deg);
  }
}
```

An intermediate keyframe solves some of the rotation issues, but messes up even more when used with multiple transforms.

How can I fix this - that is, in this example, how can I add a translation to the rotating square without having it change rotation behavior (taking the short CCW rotation to 350deg instead of the full CW rotation like it does normally without a translation)?

Here's a CodePen with some examples:
http://codepen.io/jbjw/pen/gmyajY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify the starting point of `rotate(0)`, it animates as expected.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: translate(500px) rotate(350deg);
  }
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Alternatively you can specify your `translate(0)` starting point and it will work as expected.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(500px) rotate(350deg);
  }
}



body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This works. Any idea why? I understand now that there's some kind of difference between `rotate(0deg)` to `rotate(350deg)` and `no rotation` to `rotate(350deg)` - seems akin to `null` vs `undefined`, but I don't understand why the difference has the effect of changing rotation behavior (shortcutting to 350deg).

Comment: @jbjw not sure why either. I've noticed this before so I just make it a practice now to not mis-match those, or just leave the initial state off entirely if I'm transitioning/animating from `0`. If I leave one of the transform properties out of the transition/animation, the one I left off seems to take the "path of least resistance" to finish the transition/animation. Here's an example with a transition - same thing http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpReWy

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that it sees that at 0%, you are at 0 degrees. At 100%, you are at 350degrees. This is actually just -10degrees from where you started, so it will from the start it knows it only has to rotate (-)10 degrees. You can fix this by adding in 50% and taking both the transforms half values:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpgNje

```
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(250px) rotate(175deg)
  }
  100% {
    /* transform: rotate(350deg); */
    transform: translate(500px) rotate(350deg);
  }
}
```